# Code Perl on Android

Tags: android, mysql, perl

I am wanting to install Perl onto my android phone (2.3.4) so that I can sit on the tube/train etc and code projects on it using Vi etc.

I have found a few articles about how to code android IN perl, but I don't want to do that. I merely want to code actual perl projects but using my phone as a computer.

I'm presuming that as android is linux based it should be possible, and I know that busybox exists that has a load of linux/unix commands.

So what I'm asking is what are the steps I need to take, can I just install the normal perl program on it, or does it have to be tailored to work with android and maybe has someone already done this out there?

Also I'd need to be able to put MySQL or SQL on it.

Lots of thanks in advance.

Russ

Comment: Wait, do you have vi working on your android device? How'd you get this?

Comment: As far as I know, Perl code can not be launched on Android. Why don't you use Bash?

Comment: Kurtis, No I don't have Vi. I just assumed it would be on the linux command line thing (if I could get it installed!?)

Comment: Gnufable - Bash...I've never totally understood what that is? Isn't it just the name for the command line terminal in linux?

Answer (score 9):

[PerlDroid](http://code.google.com/p/perldroid/)

> This project aims to port the language Perl on Android. The minimal Android version to run it is 1.6.

---

[SL4A on Android](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/)

> Scripts can be run interactively in a terminal, in the background, or via Locale. Python, Perl, JRuby, Lua, BeanShell, JavaScript, Tcl, and shell are currently supported, and we're planning to add more

Comment: I recommend SL4a, I tried using it with Python and it worked.

Comment: Perldroid might seem to be what I'm after but it looks like no-ones working on it as it mentions Android 1.6 which is old now.

SL4A isn't what I'm after. That would be for building android based apps, but using Perl instead of Java. 

I don't want to write things FOR my phone, I just want to use my phone to code other projects to run on my home pc. I just want to be able to use my phone to code when I'm on the move. Kind of like using a laptop.

Thanks though...

Comment: @RussWheeler, I didn't installed any of those yet, but... **the first one** is active! yep, it support old android version, but it seems to be active project with current activities. The **second** project can let you run your script locally. It might run scripts that you will write down your **note** application, and let you debug them during your commute...